# Members only have the access to add to cart button shopify?

Tags: html, shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-template

I hope you are doing great.
I'm looking for the code or shopify app that will allow me the option that is when a specific Member is only that member can see the add to cart button. For other customer that are not members of the site can't see the add to cart button.
Is there anything you can help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please update your question and provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
with relevant code parts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use shopify apps for this.
You can add a filter to detect customers who are logged in or not.
You have to wrape the `add to cart form` inside the condition.

```
    {% if customer %}
              // add_to_cart form/liquid
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible in Front-end part or client side.

To view the particular attribute or design by some condition you have to use some logic in backend or some jQuery with preloaded data.

Comment: Why is jQuery required? Why not with just JavaScript?

Comment: You can use both I prefer jQuery.

Comment: can you help me with that?

Comment: Which backend language you are using ?

Comment: liquid files as shopify based on